# How should legal questions be handled?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282238/playing-youtube-videos-in-customized-avplayer-is-against-youtubes-terms) with a custom flag stating that it isn't a programming related question.

Obviously this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, as you can tell by the question:

> but my concern is whether this is against the Terms of YouTube or not

Although the true question is hidden behind programming terms (ex. `AVPlayer`), this is **not** a programming question.

At the time there was a bounty on this question, so I decided to flag it with a custom flag. There also isn't a really good flag that fits this situation. There are flags to move a question to other sites on Stack Exchange, but nothing really directly fit this question.

The flag was declined with "declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?".

What is the suggested method for handling this in the future?

---

As I mentioned, "At the time there was a bounty on this question". As far as I'm aware, you can't vote to close an issue with an active bounty. The solutions to deal with issues on questions with active bounties is limited.

Comment: @JeanneDark As what? There isn't really a good category for it. And can you even vote to close with questions that have a bounty? I thought that wasn't allowed.

Comment: @JeanneDark Within that article I'd argue that the fact that it had a bounty, falls under the category: `Something requires specific attention, and can't reasonably be handled without superpowers`. I don't think you can vote to close with questions that have an active bounty.

Comment: Interesting, the linked question has since been closed and deleted by a mod, with the comment *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the help center. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [Law.se]."*

Comment: @JeanneDark you can't vote to close a bountied question.

Comment: When something has a bounty and you can't close but are sure it should be closed, you can include "I cannot close because question has a bounty" so mod can see clearly why you're flagging instead of VTCing

Comment: Please share the contents of your flag, otherwise it's hard to tell what you might have done incorrectly. My guess is you didn't mention that the question has a bounty on it.

Comment: My flag was: `This is a legal question (not a programming question) which doesn’t belong on SO`. Thanks for all the advice!! Next time I will be clear in my flag message that it has an active bounty, so I can't vote to close.

Comment: The information you're missing is that when handling flags, moderators, by default, see only a small amount of context about the post. We, obviously, can get more context, but there needs to be some indication that we should look at that additional context. We also get a lot of custom flags which are basically "please close this". There's also an easy, stock decline response which is to use "standard" flags. So, make sure that your custom flag gives us an indication of the actual problem (in this case that you *couldn't* vote to close because of the bounty).

Comment: While there might have reasonably been enough information that the moderator could have checked for more context (e.g. to see there was a bounty), it's clear that didn't happen, or that communication broke down between what you were trying to tell the moderators and how the flag was interpreted when handled. The question is handled at this point, which is good. I understand that having the flag in the declined state is frustrating, but moderators *can't* change that. After a flag is helpful/declined/retracted, we can only change spam and rude/abusive flags, which we can mark as "disputed".

Comment: Thank you @Makyen. As a user who has never been a moderator myself, it's helpful to understand the perspective of what moderators see here. Maybe there is also potential for the SO team to make UI improvements to that interface to give clarity (like open bounties) and other useful information in your interface?? Not sure if that idea has been explored before.

Comment: Why do you need to flag it as a custom flag? Just flag it as `needs improvement` -> `A community-specific reason` -> `Blatantly off-topic`.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Because you cannot vote to close (flag) a question that has active bounty.